# How to put double value in a JavaCv Matrix?

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

In javaCv how can I put a double value into a Mat object in a specific position? 
I need to do something like Mat.put(int row, int col, double d)

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert in JavaCV, but:

Something like this with an Indexer:

```
CvMat mat = CvMat.create(3, 3);.
DoubleIndexer matIdx= mat.createIndexer();

double d = 1.0;
...
matIdx.put(i, j, d);
```

Or

```
opencv_core.cvSet2D(mat , i, j, d);
```

Or using

```
void CvMat::put(int i, int j, double v)
```